# Moving a database in netbeans to another computer

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, derby

I made a fairly small java program in netbeans, with the database saved in the scr folder under database/mainUserData, On my main pc, if i export it to a .jar folder, It works, If i copy all the data in the folder (70mb's worth) to another pc, it can't find the database any more, I made sure to add code that always uses the current directory in the jar folder as a url to the database, this is the connection code:

```
myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MainUserData", "jacovanstryp", "Password1234");
```

Why is it when i move it to another computer (The whole file, it no longer knows where the database is?

What I have Tried:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/com/vanstryp/res/Database/MainUserData"); // This is the same directory as where the .jar is located
```

This just returns Null.

This is the top Error code it returns

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused: connect.
```

This is the code for the method I used

```
  public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        //This code will connect the database to the java program
        //Information to connect database obtained from -->  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7RZV4VLv3s
        Connection myconObj = null; //allows to connect to database
        Statement mystatObj = null; // create statement (Execute queries)
        ResultSet myresObj = null; // get result
        ResultSetMetaData mymeta = null;

        try {

            String query = "select * from JACOVANSTRYP.MAINUSERDATA";
            URL databaseLocation = this.getClass().getResource("/com/vanstryp/database/MainUserData/");

            myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:/" + databaseLocation, "jacovanstryp", "Eduplex1234");
            mystatObj = myconObj.createStatement();
            myresObj = mystatObj.executeQuery(query);
            mymeta = myresObj.getMetaData();
            int colomnNo = mymeta.getColumnCount();

            while (myresObj.next()) {
                String dbUsername = myresObj.getString("Username");
                String dbPassword = myresObj.getString("Password");
                System.out.println();
                if (username.equalsIgnoreCase(dbUsername) && password.equals(dbPassword)) {

                    PrintWriter activeUser = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("activeUser.db"));
                    activeUser.println(dbUsername);
                    activeUser.close();
                    return true;

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    } catch

 (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(commonMethods.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Another nice question here ... and welcome to upvote levels. So when you decide to keep your other accept in place, you are now able to show your appreciation for hopefully helpful input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MainUserData", ...);
```

uses a connection string of `"jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MainUserData"`. That means that you have setup (maybe through Netbeans) a Derby server on that computer listening on port 1527.

Copying a jar and the file backing the database is not enough: you must start the Derby server on the new host or use the one from the old host:

```
myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://other.host.full.name:1527/MainUserData", ...);
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the *embedded* mode of Derby. Then you just have to declare which folder contains the database file:

```
myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:/path/to/MainUserData", ...);
```

In this mode, you can just copy both the jar (and its optional other files) and the database to the new system, and it should find the database if you give a correct path.

Comment: Is there a way to allow the program to access this database without starting it on the new host? For example if i were to upload this online and allow people to download it, how would i change it to where the program can still access it without the user downloading netbeans and starting it up again?

Comment: JavaDB can be used in embedded mode. In that mode it does not depend on an external server but only on the path of the folder hosting the database. Please see my edit

Comment: If i do what you suggested, i get this error -  java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:/file:/C:/Users/Jaco%20van%20Stryp/Dropbox/Fitness%20Perfect/build/classes/com/vanstryp/database/MainUserData ---- This is my code-  URL databaseLocation = this.getClass().getResource("/com/vanstryp/database/MainUserData");

            myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:/" + databaseLocation, "jacovanstryp", "Password1234");

Comment: Two problems here. First is simple: you must load the embedded driver with `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");` and not the `ClientDriver`. Second is different: you search the database under build/classes which is bad: only read only file should lie there.

Comment: I added all the code for this method, Could you explain what you mean by "Second is different: you search the database under build/classes which is bad: only read only file should lie there" and possibly correct the code? Databases are fairly new to me.

Comment: It needs to know where the database is regardless on where the jar/lib file is.